# C# вернутся на каталог назад

Tags: c#, directory

Как вернутся на пару папок назад

допустим данный код :

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Example2.txt";
```

возвращает D:\code\SumElementsTask\bin\Debug\net5.0\Example2.txt

как сделать так чтобы возвращалось - D:\code\SumElementsTask\Example2.txt

Comment: var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"..\..\Example2.txt";   так не работает?

Comment: @xmikex неа, выводит = "D:\code\SumElementsTask\bin\Debug\net5.0..\..\Example2.txt"
p.s. так же находил на форумах и пытался так сделать, но почему то не работает

Comment: `new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov работает, спасибо :)

Comment: Файл `Example2.txt` включен в состав проекта? Если да, то задайте ему в Свойствах (Properties) Copy to Output Directory значение "Copy if newer". Тогда не нужно будет искать родительские папки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не пробовал ещё добавлять в состав проекта, посмотрю разберусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Example2.txt");
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string parent = Directory.GetParent(dir).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(path);
Console.WriteLine(dir);
Console.WriteLine(parent);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
C:\Projects\PathTest\Example2.txt
C:\Projects\PathTest
C:\Projects
```